# CiviCRM does not update status of PayPal Standard transactions after update to 5.27.2

Tags: civicontribute, paypal, ipn

Wordpress 5.4.2, CiviCRM 5.27.2

After updating CiviCRM to the latest version (5.27.2) CiviCRM stopped updating the status of contributions when payment is made using PayPal Standard payment procesor. The payment is processed correctly (money left contributor account and was received by the organisation), however the contribution in CiviCRM is still in Pending status and moreover the confirmation email was not sent to the contributor.

I've read the [CiviCRM 5.26 and WordPress Important Notice](https://civicrm.org/blog/kcristiano/civicrm-526-and-wordpress-important-notice) and I understand that there are some changes in paths, but the page does not provide a clear guide on how to update the PayPal IPN settings. In the past I used just the domain name (https://example.com) for the Notification URL in and it worked without major issues. Now it appears to stooped working. I also tried to update the notification URL in line with the guidelines from [Recurring Contributions and Webhooks](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/recurring/#IPN%20notify%20URL) using the updated path i.e. https://www.example.com/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/payment/ipn/1 but this also does not work.

Is this an issue with Civi/PayPal or am I missing something important?

Comment: I am also at Wordpress 5.4.2 and CiviCRM 5.27.2. I have PayPal Standard, although I recently switched to the PayPal Checkout support available with the Omnipay extension.  I can still enable the PayPal Standard payment processor and it seems to be behaving properly, at least for test/sandbox transactions.  https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor/blob/master/docs/Paypal.md

Comment: Do you use Cleaner URLs? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/#enabling-cleaner-urls-for-wordpress

Comment: Not really. Do you think I should install the plugin?

Comment: No, I was just trying to assess your implementation in comparison to mine. I do use Cleaner URLs, although I don't think it impacts this issue. I also have just my domain name for the IPN notification URL. Do you see any errors in the CiviCRM Log Viewer? A successful payment confirmation should look something like "`PayPalIPN: Received (ContactID: 2; trxn_id: 8A959209KY580015Y)`"

Comment: I tried enabling Cleaner URL's, but that does not seem to work either. I tried different settings for IPN including simply specifying the domain, however I still get errors in my log, such as this one:

"[debug] $backTrace = #0 {main_dir}/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(432): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 {main_dir}/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))"

Comment: I see that error on a regular basis (2-3 times per day) but I don't believe it is associated with payments. You can check the details of live webhook events on developer.paypal.com in the left side menu. I look at pairs of transaction events for "payment created" and "sale completed". Click on an event for details. You should find the URL it used.

I have my callback URL (Cleaner URL format) specified in the webhook section under "My Apps and Credentials".

Comment: In case you haven't seen the announcement of this new extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/easy-ipn-url. It's a nice way to check you IPN URL.

Comment: I'm having similar issues with Paypal Standard. See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1931 for more info on what I've tried by way of 307 rewrite rules. Would love to see a solution to this.

Comment: @Graham, Thanks for info and opening the issue. I agree this looks like a bug, which impares the paypal-civicrm functionality. Hopefully it will get fixed soon. In the meantime do you know if there are any workarounds for the problem?